# Dynamic Instruction Count

Tags: mips

How do you determine the dynamic instruction count of a program?

Comment: Could you define "dynamic instruction count" for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very much depends on your platform, but one option may be to measure using clock() .

Comment: What if you were just analyzing a code snippet and you wanted to determine the dynamic instruct count? Would it be dependent on how many statements there are and the loop?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can calculate that by looking at the assembly code, look at how many cycles each instruction take, and multiply inner loop cycles with loop count.